# React: useContext vs variables to store cache

Tags: reactjs

I have the following code which I implemented caching for my users:

```
import { IUser } from "../../context/AuthContext";

export const usersCache = {};

export const fetchUserFromID = async (id: number): Promise<IUser> => {
  try {
    const res = await fetch("users.json");
    const users = await res.json();
    Object.keys(users).forEach((userKey) => {
      const currentUser = users[userKey];

      if (!currentUser) {
        console.warn(`Found null user:  ${userKey}`);
        return;
      }
      usersCache[users[userKey].id] = currentUser;
    });

    const user = usersCache[id];
    return user;
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(`Failed to fetch user from ID: ${id}`, e);
    throw Error("Unable to fetch the selected user.");
  }
};
```

As you can see, the variable `userCache` stores all the users.
It works fine and I can access this variable from all my components.

I decided that I want to "notify" all my components that the `userCache` has changed, and I had to move this logic to a react `Context` and consume it with `useContext`.

So the questions are:

1. How I can set the userCache context although the above code is not a react component? (it's just a typescript file I called 'UserService')?

I can't do:

```
export const fetchUserFromID = async (id: number): Promise<IUser> => {
  const { setUserCache } = useContext(MembersContext);
...
}

React Hook "useContext" is called in function "fetchUserFromID" that is neither a React function component nor a custom React Hook function. React component names must start with an uppercase letter. (react-hooks/rules-of-hooks)eslint
```

2. Is there a reason to prefer Context over variable as above altough the data is not subject to change frequently?

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure what you exactly asking here but as far as I can say, you need to store the data in a state so you can manipulate and do stuff etc... And useState can only be used inside of a component, which should be context provider component in this case.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. How I can set the userCache context although the above code is not a react component? (it's just a typescript file I called 'UserService')?

You need to declare your context value somewhere in a component in order to use it.

```
const MembersContext = React.createContext({}); // initial value here

function App() {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState({});

  const fetchUserFromID = async (id: number) => {
    /* ... */
    // This will call `setUsers`
    /* ... */
  }

  return (
    <MembersContext.Provider value={users}>
       {/* your app components, `fetchUserFromId` is passed down */}
    </MembersContext.Provider>
  );
}

function SomeComponent() {
   const users = useContext(MembersContext);

   return (/* you can use `users` here */);
}
```

> 2. Is there a reason to prefer Context over variable as above altough the data is not subject to change frequently?

If you need your components to update when the data changes you have to go with either :

- a context
- a state passed down through props
- a redux state

More info [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) on how to use Contexts.